# Pulling <identity> strings

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my Web.Config file, I have

```
<identity userName="CTX_DOMAIN\ldapuser" password="ldapPW" />
```

How can I pull these userName and password strings in my C# behind code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
    System.Web.Configuration.IdentitySection identityInfo = (System.Web.Configuration.IdentitySection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/identity");
    string userName = identityInfo.UserName;
    string password = identityInfo.Password;
```